# Is there a way to use a JavaScript script in the html code of a WordPress article?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

So, I have a very simple JavaScript code that make a text appear letter by letter, it's working, it's nice, I like it, is there a way to use it in a WordPress article or to reproduce the same result without using any WordPress plugins ?

(I'm a very beginner at WordPress).

I tried to simply add a script balise in the html of the article but WordPress simply delete it.

Apparently I'm bad at searching the web since I did find problems close to mine, but not really helpful solutions, apparently there is a way to modify the files of the WordPress site without using WordPress, but I didn't succeeded to make it work).

```
<script>
  var div = document.getElementById("pdj");
  var srcText = div.innerHTML;
  div.innerHTML = "";
  const delayInMilliseconds = 80;
  var i = 0;

  var writeText = setInterval(function () {
    div.innerHTML += srcText[i];
    console.log(srcText[i]);
    i++;
  }, delayInMilliseconds);

  setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(writeText); //clear above interval after 5 seconds
  }, delayInMilliseconds * (srcText.length));
</script>
```

So I would like to find a way to use this script or to reproduce is behavior in a WordPress article without any plugin (since I don't have the expensive membership that permit it) , I'm not really looking for THE solution (I will not refuse it if you have it), I'm more looking for a direction for where I should search / look to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like youll need to learn to add custom js to the wp site which is usually done with directly entering the script to the header of the page or uploading your own js file as a custom plugin. Theres a great guide on OST for it here in both manners. https://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/custom-js/